# How to take string with space in match case in Python 3.10

Tags: python, match, python-3.10

I've a code in python 3.10 with a match - case structure. It's a terminal's apps, with command. How to take all the text after the "cesar" in one variable? Because space break the commands.

```
user= input("->")
match user.split():
    case["cesar" ,mot]:
        cesar(mot)
    case _:
        print("your answer is incorrect")
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you can use the [`cmd` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) if you prefer to not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

Use `*` to match a sublist, just like you would in a function parameter list to get all the remaining arguments.

```
match user.split():
    case ["cesar", *mot]:
        cesar(mot)
    case _:
        print("your answer is incorrect")
```

Answer (score 2):

For "all the text after `cesar` in one variable", if you mean as one `str` variable, use `maxsplit=1`; otherwise, Barmar's answer is probably what you want:

```py
def cesar(mot):
    print(f'{mot=}')

user= input("->")
match user.split(maxsplit=1):
    case["cesar" ,mot]:
        cesar(mot)
    case _:
        print("your answer is incorrect")
```

Output:

```
->cesar one two three
mot='one two three'
```